# VS2019 BitBucket Permission denied (public key)

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I'm having a curious problem where pushing/pulling my bitbucket repository using SourceTree works, but I get a permission denied error when using VS2019, .

I checked that the repository repository name & path, login username & email are the same for both SourceTree and VS2019. I'm using Pageant for ssh authentication.

Any clues why I'm getting the error only in VS2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70304583/6309), you need to add the server's key to PuTTY's storage, or to upgrade [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases). And make sure to set a Windows User environment variable to `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`.

But the alternative is to use a plain openSSH key, as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59973208/6309).